# Linux Segmentation fault with fopen

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code? I keep getting segmentation fault

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *in, *out;
    in = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    out = fopen(argv[2],"w");
    fseek(in,0,SEEK_END);
    ...
    fseek(in,0,SEEK_SET);
```

I did ./a.out filename1 filename2

I tried copying the arguments into string variables and I didn't have any problems

```
char f1[100],f2[100];
strcpy(f1,argv[1]);
strcpy(f2,argv[2]);
FILE *in, *out;
in = fopen(f1,"r");
out = fopen(f2,"w");
```

Comment: I tried copying the arguments into strings variables and it works, is this really necessary? I never got a segmentation fault passing in arguments in fopen before

Comment: This looks fine, maybe print out argc or argv to make sure you're actually receiving the arguments

Comment: I tried doing that as well it prints out the argc and argv but after calling fopen it gives me segmentation fault

Comment: Which fopen? Could be either one... Put some code between them to see which is crashing

Comment: Please edit your examples so they are _minimal, complete and verifiable_: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. What's the minimum code to reproduce the segfault? What did you try to debug it? What about using a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know what's wrong with this code?

You don't have any error checking code. You assume the calls to `fopen` are successful.

```
in = fopen(argv[1],"r");
if ( in == NULL )
{
   // Problem opening the file.
   // Print the cause of the problem and exit.
   perror("Unable to open the file");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Add similar code for `out`.

Comment: the files exist, i tried doing that and still gives me segmentation fault

Comment: In that case, I would recommend posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The files may exist and it could still fail if you don't have permission to write or read